# Safe way to update MySQL user password

Tags: mysql, sql, security, change-password

As far as I'm aware, there are 3 mechanisms that one can use to update a user's password in MySQL (and its variants).

1. `ALTER USER 'user'@'host' IDENTIFIED BY 'pw';`
2. `SET PASSWORD FOR 'user' = PASSWORD('pw');`
3. `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('pw') WHERE User = 'user' AND Host = 'host';`

Of those, only #3 can be executed using *prepared statements*.

As of MariaDB 10.4, the `mysql.user` table is now a view - so this mechanism will not work, plus it feels very hacky to be messing about with the `mysql` database in any case.

#1 and #2 are vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks since they cannot be prepared, so hence the question:

Is there a safe way to update a MySQL user's password?

Comment: Why would you expect to update MySQL user passwords in a web interface?

Comment: I work for a web-hosting company

Comment: Still not really sure why you would do this on a web interface in an interactive manner that would require you to use parametrized queries. The password should be generated by the tenant management software without any user input.

Comment: These comments are irrelevant to the problem at hand

Comment: I disagree. The root cause of the problem is that you seem to be trying to move functionality to an interacative web application, that you really should not. If the passwords were generated by a application, not through user input, then you would not have this problem in the first place!

Comment: Regardless of _how_ a feature is used, it should still be usable in a safe way. Your decree that I'm "doing it wrong" without knowing my use-case is unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PDO, escape the password with [`PDO::quote()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php).

If you're using MySQLi, use [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score -1):

You need to use first two methods to change password in mariadb 10.4.

As They have different authentication plugin now and storing passwords in ***global_priv*** instead of ***user*** table.

Recommend to do through localhost only and avoid through TCP and disable history.